# How to estimate the lambda parameter in EWMA in excel solver

Tags: finance, risk-management

So I have a simple enough assignment question. I was asked to find the EWMA for daily stock returns of a given firm. When I was answering the Garch problem, I had multiple variables- alpha, beta, unconditional variance and I used the log likelihood as well.

I ran the initial EWMA using a lambda of 0.94, but my professor wants me to use solver to find the appropriate lambda. How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use Solver to minimize a function that you choose. By minimizing a measure of 'lack of fit' you can find a value of lambda that fits the data well.